# Assigning a unique index to each character (not character position!) within a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign a unique index between 0 and N (where n is the number of unique characters within the string) to the characters in a UTF32 string.

For example, if I had the string "hello", the output of the function would be:

```
'h' = 0
'e' = 1
'l' = 2
'o' = 3
```

There are 4 unique characters in the string "hello", so the output would need to be between 0 and 3.

I know this can be done using a hash table quite easily, or even minimal perfect hashing. What I'm curious about is if there's a more efficient way of handling this task, since I only ever need to map a single character to a single output value (I don't need to hash entire strings, for example). Because of this, using something like std::map seems a bit overkill, however I've not been able to find mention of any alternative that would be any faster to initialize or evaluate (though I suppose you could just shove the characters in a sorted array and look them up using a binary search).

Comment: "more efficient". What does that even mean? For a single query, using a hash table is very inefficient. You're not going to beat `std::string("hello").find('h')`.

Comment: The amount of shortcuts depends so strongly on the input data, that you should check first if you can somehow limit those and analyze them. If you are truly after full Utf32, then using hashed map is probably reasonable base, from which you can check if you can further improve, but full Utf32 has too many codepoints to use some of ASCII-like tricks...

Comment: Are you sure you want unique codepoints and not unique [graphemes](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) [aka grapheme cluster] (and after applying a normalization form)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using UTF32 strings, I'm assuming this is for a good reason, namely that you want to support a huge amount of different characters and symbols from all over the world. If you cannot make any assumption at all about which characters you will be most likely dealing with, I think the answer of Some programmer dude is your best bet.

However, `std::unordered_set` is known to be much slower than a simple array lookup, as proposed by Max Langhof. So, if you *can* make some assumptions, you may be able to combine these two ideas.

For example, if you can reasonably assume that most of your input will be ASCII characters, you can use something like this:

```
constexpr char32_t ExpectedStart = U' '; // space == 32
constexpr char32_t ExpectedEnd = 128;

int main()
{
    std::basic_string<char32_t> input = U"Hello €";

    std::array<bool, ExpectedEnd - ExpectedStart> fastLookup;
    std::fill(fastLookup.begin(), fastLookup.end(), false);
    std::unordered_set<char32_t> slowLookup;

    for (auto c : input)
    {
        if (ExpectedStart <= c && c < ExpectedEnd)
            fastLookup[c - ExpectedStart] = true;
        else
            slowLookup.insert(c);
    }

    size_t unique_id = 0;
    for (char32_t c = ExpectedStart; c < ExpectedEnd; ++c)
        if (fastLookup[c - ExpectedStart])
            std::wcout << '\'' << (wchar_t)c << "' = " << unique_id++ << '\n';

    for (auto c : slowLookup)
        std::wcout << '\'' << (wchar_t)c << "' = " << unique_id++ << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oS46gQqcL5Af9X9H).

Note that for printing purposes I casted the chars to `wchar_t` as it is apparently quite difficult to properly print `char32_t`. But I'm assuming your final goal is not printing anyway, so I hope this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a hash-table (in the form of [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)) to store the unique letters, then just use a simple counter when the output is needed.

Something like

```
std::string str = "hello";

std::unordered_set<char> chars(begin(str), end(str));
std::size_t counter = 0;
for (char c : chars)
    std::cout << '\'' << c << "' = " << counter++ << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

> any alternative that would be any faster to initialize or evaluate

You're not going to get faster than a `std::unordered_map<char, size_t>` as you have to check if you've already seen a `char` before you know if you need to store a new `char` --> `size_t` map for it.

Unless, of course, you write a better unordered map.  As @MaxLanghof points out: this can be done with something like a `std::array<char, 256>` intitailsed to a *not found* value.

Comment: I have doubts about any statement containing _"you're not going to get faster than `std::unordered_map`"_. In fact, `std::array<char, 256>` mapping character to unique index (with some sentinel value for "unseen") is equivalent to a perfect-hash hashtable lookup and guaranteed to be an order of magnitude faster than a `std::unordered_map` lookup. Now this may not be feasible for 32 bit characters (which `char` is decidedly not), but as written your answer is definitely not correct.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Taking *initilize* into the equation.  You're going to have to linearly search your `std:array<char>` for every `char` in the string during initialization..

Comment: You walk through the string char by char, look each one up in your array map. If it's already been assigned an index, continue, otherwise increment the number of seen chars and store the new unique index in the map. That's `O(N)`, which is obviously minimal.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Ah, just saw it's a `std::array<char, 256>`. Yeah - agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with 8 bit chars, you can use `std::array<char, 256>` map from `char` to unique index (which obviously fits into a `char` too):

```
constexpr unsigned char UNASSIGNED = 255; // Could be another character but then the loop logic gets harder.
std::array<unsigned char, 256> indices;
std::fill(indices.begin(), indices.end(), UNASSIGNED);

std::string input = ...;
unsigned char nextUniqueIndex = 0;
for (unsigned char c : input)
  if (indices[c] == UNASSIGNED)
  {
    indices[c] = nextUniqueIndex;
    ++nextUniqueIndex;
  }

// indices now contains a mapping of each char in the input to a unique index.
```

This of course requires that your input string doesn't use the entire value range of `char` (or rather that there are not 256 distinct characters in the input).

Now, you said that you are working with UTF32 which doesn't make this solution immediately viable. Indeed, for 32-bit characters the map would require 16 GB of memory (which would not perform well in any case). But if you actually receive 2<sup>32</sup> different UTF32 characters in random order then you're already at 16 GB input data, so at this point the question is "what assumptions can you make about your input data that can be exploited to improve the lookup" (presumably in the form of a good hashing function) and what kind of hash table gives you the best performance. I would wager that `std::unordered_map` with its separate allocations per key-value-pair and linked list traversal on lookup will not result in peak performance.

The sorting approach you mentioned is one such option, but if e.g. the entire input is a mix of two character this will not be "efficient" either compared to other approaches. I will also drop the keyword [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) here as, for large data volumes, it might be a good way to handle frequently seen characters quickly (i.e. having a separate data structure for frequent keys vs infrequent keys).